# PHP loop through parent child menu items from exported product catalogue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This one is a little tough,
I have imported a list of products from ACTINIC to a mysql database. I need to be able to collect all products from a top level menu item and put all of the child menu items in an array so i can look up which products belong to said top level item.

All the menu items have id's that are sequential starting from 1.

i need a way of looping through an undetermined amount of child items based on their parent id's and to collect all of there id's into an array to be used to loop up the products.

I think i have explained that well enough, any help or ideas would be great. Just need a starting point then i can go from here.

// EDIT

Thanks johan for pointing me in the right direction

```
// $all is a mysql query
loopit($all);
function loopit($array){

    while($forone = mysql_fetch_array($array)){

        echo "id=" . $forone['nSectionID'] . " name=" . $forone['Section text'] . "<br />";

        $seltwo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE nParentSectionID='" . $forone['nSectionID'] . "'");

        loopit($seltwo);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a recursive function for that. Something like this:

```
function import ( $items ) {
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    // handle item import
    // .....

    if ( $item->children ) {
      import( $item->children ); // Notice the function calling itself here.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok i was thinking along these lines, i think there is something i can do. The menu items aren't clear as to if their a parent/child but im sure i can think of something. thanks for the pointer

Comment: No problem, try to implement it. If you get lost, update your question ^^

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! got a nice little loop set up which does the job. I dont use PHPOO so i used a while loop instead,

i edited my initial post to show the solution

please ignore my terrible variable names haha